# Tic Tac Toe – Output Prints an Extra Line

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write the game Tic Tac Toe. This game involves two players, where each player takes a turn to place either a X or an O (depending on the player) in a 2-dimensional grid. The x and y coordinates lie within the range [0-2] (inclusive). A player (X or O) can win if they have 3 in a row, column or diagonal.

The program is almost correct, when 'X' or 'O' wins, the program gives a correct output that not print one empty line before 'X wins!' or 'O wins', however, the program print one empty lines before print 'Draw' when draw, the expected output should not print a empty line before print 'Draw'. I don't know how to fix it.

```
def print_matric(eri):
    for j in range(0,3):
        for i in range(0,3):
            if eri[i][j]==-1:
                print(" ",end="")
            if eri[i][j]==0:
                print("O",end="");
            if eri[i][j]==1:
                print("X",end="");
            if not i==2:
                print("|",end="");
        print()
        # prints ("_ _ _") two times only not third time
        if not j==2:
            print("-----",end="")
        print()
def compute(eri):
    if eri[0][0]== eri[0][1] and eri[0][1] == eri[0][2] and eri[0][0] != -1:
        return eri[0][0]
    if eri[1][0]== eri[1][1] and eri[1][1] == eri[1][2] and eri[1][0] != -1:
        return eri[1][0]
    if eri[2][0]== eri[2][1] and eri[2][1] == eri[2][2] and eri[2][0] != -1:
        return eri[2][0]
    if eri[0][0]== eri[1][0] and eri[1][0] == eri[2][0] and eri[0][0] != -1:
        return eri[0][0]
    if eri[0][1]== eri[1][1] and eri[1][1] == eri[2][1] and eri[0][1] != -1:
        return eri[0][1]
    if eri[0][2]== eri[1][2] and eri[1][2] == eri[2][2] and eri[0][2] != -1:
        return eri[0][2]
    if eri[0][0]== eri[1][1] and eri[1][1] == eri[2][2] and eri[0][0] != -1:
        return eri[0][0]
    if eri[0][2]== eri[1][1] and eri[1][1] == eri[2][0] and eri[0][2] != -1:
        return eri[0][2]
    return -1
def find_whether_empty(eri):
    for j in range(0,3):
        for i in range(0,3):
            if eri[j][i]==-1:
                return 1
    return 0
eri = [[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1]]
count=0
while True:
    a,b = input().split()
    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)  
    if a<0 or a>2 or b<0 or b>2:
        print("\ncheck your coordinates and enter again")
        continue
    if not eri[a][b]==-1:
        print("\nposition already occupied, please enter again")
        continue
    if count%2==0:
        eri[a][b]=1
    else:
        eri[a][b]=0
    count=count+1
    if compute(eri)==-1:
        print()  
    x=compute(eri)
    if not x==-1:
        if x==0:
            print("O wins!\n")
        else:
            print("X wins!\n")
    if not find_whether_empty(eri):
        print("Draw\n")
        print_matric(eri)
        break
    print_matric(eri)
    if not x==-1:
        break
```

Expected output:

```
0 0               

X| |
-----
 | |
-----
 | |

1 1

X| |
-----
 |O|
-----
 | |

1 0

X|X|
-----
 |O|
-----
 | |

2 0

X|X|O
-----
 |O|
-----
 | |

0 2

X|X|O
-----
 |O|
-----
X| |

0 1

X|X|O
-----
O|O|
-----
X| |

2 1

X|X|O
-----
O|O|X
-----
X| |

2 2

X|X|O
-----
O|O|X
-----
X| |O

1 2
Draw

X|X|O
-----
O|O|X
-----
X|X|O
```

Actual output:

```
0 0

X| | 
-----
 | | 
-----
 | | 

1 1

X| | 
-----
 |O| 
-----
 | | 

1 0

X|X| 
-----
 |O| 
-----
 | | 

2 0

X|X|O
-----
 |O| 
-----
 | | 

0 2

X|X|O
-----
 |O| 
-----
X| | 

0 1

X|X|O
-----
O|O| 
-----
X| | 

2 1

X|X|O
-----
O|O|X
-----
X| | 

2 2

X|X|O
-----
O|O|X
-----
X| |O

1 2

Draw

X|X|O
-----
O|O|X
-----
X|X|O
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove these 2 commented lines, and add the `print()` to be run only when the game didn't end:

```
if count%2==0:
    eri[a][b]=1
else:
    eri[a][b]=0
count=count+1
# if compute(eri)==-1:  # REMOVED THESE
#     print()           # REMOVED THESE
x=compute(eri)
if not x==-1:
    if x==0:
        print("O wins!\n")
    else:
        print("X wins!\n")
elif not find_whether_empty(eri):  # CHANGED if -> elif
    print("Draw\n")
    print_matric(eri)
    break
else:        # ADDED THESE
    print()  # ADDED THESE
```

> Then it will give the correct output when drawn:
>
> ```
> ......
> ......
> O|X| 
> -----
> X|O|O
> -----
> X| |X
>
> 1 2
>
> O|X| 
> -----
> X|O|O
> -----
> X|O|X
>
> 2 0
> Draw
>
> O|X|X
> -----
> X|O|O
> -----
> X|O|X
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This answer exists to impart further advice that will (hopefully) carry on into the future whenever you need to write and debug code.

**A clear flow of logic and structure will improve your overall capacity to think straightforwardly and reason about your code.**

Currently, your code might work *logically*, but the *flow* is difficult to follow. I'm referring especially to the segment below. Comments have been added for you to follow my thought process.

```
    if compute(eri)==-1:             # ok, compute the matrix and check for no winner    
        print()
    x=compute(eri)                   # compute the matrix... again?
    if not x==-1:                    # check for winner, why not "x != -1"?
        if x==0:
            print("O wins!\n")
        else:
            print("X wins!\n")       # didn't jump out?
    if not find_whether_empty(eri):  # check matrix is full
        print("Draw\n")
        print_matric(eri)
        break                        # jump out, but not before?
    print_matric(eri)                # ok, you wanted to print the matrix here
    if not x==-1:                    # check for winner
        break                        # jump out
```

Here, it is slightly difficult to parse individual cases. If player 1 won, it would branch into `not x == -1 -> x == 0 -> print`, then the *reader* of the code has to skip a few lines to `print_matric` and then `not x == -1 -> break`. There isn't any need for code to jump into an if-statement, jump back out, and jump back into another one. Try to avoid that if possible, since it makes for difficulty in reading.

(To top that, your code misses an edge case and exhibits a behaviour which most likely conflicts with your intentions. Try to spot that edge case.)

Here's how I'd write the logic:

```
...

finished = False           # a sentry variable
while not finished:

    ...

    winner = compute(eri)

    # is there a winner?
    if winner == -1:    # no winner

        # is the board empty?
        if not find_whether_empty(eri):
            print("Draw\n")
            finished = True
        else:
            print()         # only executed when there is no winner
                            # and board isn't empty

    else:               # there is a winner

        # which winner is it?
        if winner == 0:
            print("O wins!\n")
        elif winner == 1:
            print("X wins!\n")

        finished = True

    print_matric(eri)       # matrix printed regardless of winner state
```

Here, it is clear which part of code runs for whichever state the matrix is in. If player 1 won, it will only run `else -> winner == 0 -> print`. If there is a draw, it will only run `winner == -1 -> not find_whether_empty(eri) -> print, finished`. Additionally, `compute` is only called once (saving time) and the matrix will be printed for all winner states.

Note that instead of `break`, I've used a sentry variable `finished` to control the flow of the program. Unlike `break`, which exits the loop immediately, using the sentry variable will still run the line `print_matric`.

Hope this enlightens you a bit.